# Условия для маски input в зависимости от количества символов

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, маска

Есть jquery.maskedinput с помощью которой создана маска для input с классом "nic" для ввода значений в формате 1234 х 1234 х 1234

jQuery(".nic").mask("1234 x 1234 x 1234", {placeholder: " х  х " });

Проблема заключается в том, что пользователь может вводить все три значение от 1 до 9999 и в этом случае, если к примеру ввести 11 х 123 х 6597, сохраняется в виде 1112 х 3659 х 7.

Как можно задать условия для маски в зависимости от количества введенного значения, чтобы формат всегда был правильный?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

$(selector).inputmask("9-a{1,3}9{1,3}"); или $(selector).inputmask({ regex: "\d*" }).mask(selector);